# Shopify - Venture Theme - Product Background Image

Tags: background-image, shopify

I am using Venture Theme on Shopify. I am importing product images from another website with transparent background. And in my website, i am trying to show a background image which is in the Files directory in Shopify or a gradient color.

https://mottomfreedom.com/collections/less-is-more-skull-sweetshirt/products/skull-gr-sweatshirt-less-is-more-collection

I have been searching for a while but couldn't find a similar subject.
Please can any body help me with this?

Comment: This is not the good place for this question. [Stackoverflow is for programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

@borasutcu 
Solution 1: You are using PNG image, simply convert your image to JPG and it will have a background e.g https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx82L.jpg

Solution 2: Set background to image div using CSS

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning me @Deepak :) Actually i am a visual designer. My website is is receving the product image data from a different website. There will be a  huge number of products and  several images for each product. Converting an image from png to jpeg is an easy task but it will be a time consuming process in time. I was expecting a CSS solution. I am not experienced in coding but i think a few lines of code which is going to be added to product-card.liquid or theme.scss.liquid will solve my problem permanently. I searched for similar situations but couldn't find.
If you think that this is an inappropriate question for such a platform, i can delete my post.

Comment: Open your theme.css file and add background to product-single__photo  class e.g  .product-single__photo { background: #fff;}